# Getting too many dangling images on docker-compose up

Tags: python-3.x, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to integrate python in dotnet core image as I need to execute python scripts.
When I am executing this DockerFile, lots of dangling images are created.

[Dangling Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YobVH.png)

Also, is there any proper way to integrate a python interpreter? For example, I will get a URL in the .net core container and then I want to pass that URL to the python container. How can we achieve this task? I am new to Docker.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim  AS base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wget
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.7 \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN mkdir -p tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN wget https://github.com/projectdiscovery/subfinder/releases/download/v2.4.4/subfinder_2.4.4_linux_amd64.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf subfinder_2.4.4_linux_amd64.tar.gz
RUN mv subfinder /usr/local/bin/
#Cleanup
#wget cleanup
RUN rm -f subfinder_2.4.4_linux_amd64.tar.gz
FROM base AS final
RUN mkdir app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
COPY Publish/ /app/
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "OnePenTest.Api.dll"]
```

Answer (score 1):

As Images are immutable, so any change you would do results in a new image is created because your compose file specifies the build command, so it will rerun the build command when you start the containers.

And if any files you're composing with a `COPY` change, then the current image cache is no longer used and it'll build a new image without erasing the old image.

Can use the below commands to build your file

`sudo docker-compose build --force-rm  [--build-arg key=val...] [SERVICE...]`

`docker build --rm -t <tag>`

The option `--force-rm` removes intermediate containers after a successful build.

Comment: If it's resolved your issue then can upvote it. so will be helpful for the community

Comment: Yes, I did. @Ashok I am still confused regarding running a python script from a different container. Do I need to expose the python script in a way like Flask Http endpoint? Or is there any way I can run the python script command like :

docker run -it --rm subdomainpythonimage python optsub.py -d ndtv.com -w list.txt

I need to execute commands like above from a different container. I want to pass URL to the python script.

Comment: Which question you're talking about. This is related to dangling images right

Comment: No, it's a different one. But a little bit related to this dangling image issue. Because when I am trying to install python image, lots of intermediate images are created. So, I need to use python separately but not sure how to do that

Comment: As I mentioned earlier you can copy the python tar file to the container and can untar while startup.

Answer (score 0):

Just configure your `docker-compose.yaml` then running this with this commands:

```bash
$ docker compose down --remove-orphans # if needed to stop all running containers
$ docker compose build
$ docker compose up --no-build
```

Add the flag `--no-build` in `docker compose up`.

ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/